# Numpy - Conditional Indexing using index

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I have a 2D Numpy array i want to modify with classical conditional indexing:

```
array[array>threshold] = np.nan
```

But i want to implement a conditional that utilizes the index of the element, so as to compare with a different array. For example:

```
arr[ arr[i] * scale[i] > threshold] = np.nan
```

How would i do that?

I tried something with enumeration, but the delays became enormous.

Comment: Could you give us a (preferably small) example of what you'd like to do? It's okay to give a slow pseudocode version.

Comment: I want to implement different thresholds for each element, sort of.
Specifically, I want to scale each of my elements by a different scaler before comparing to the threshold.
`arr[ arr[i] * scale[i] > threshold] = np.nan`

Comment: I think you might just be able to write `arr[ arr * scale > threshold] = np.nan`? It depends a bit on the shape of the `scale` array

Comment: Alternatively, you could also make the threshold an array instead of a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment and revised question, this might be what you need

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(5, 5)
indices_x, indices_y = np.indices(arr.shape, sparse=True)

# return all elements from arr where x indices * 1.5 is greater than 2, similar for y indices
arr[indices_x[indices_x * 1.5 > 2], indices_y[indices_y * 1.3 > 2]]
```

Comment: Excuse me, I wasn't very clear. I want to compare each element to a threshold (number) and make any excessive elements NaN.
But let's say that there is a different threshold for each element, so I need the variable index in the conditional, not slicing based on index.

Comment: I updated the answer, is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For one-dimensional arrays you could use `np.where` to get the indices of the array and apply those in the conditional indexing.

```py
array = np.random.randn(5)
>>> [-0.65572047  0.39725663 -0.2727869  -1.62292975  0.12211058]

# Use np.where to return indices
np.where(array)[0]
>>> [0 1 2 3 4]

# Condition can include indices like this:
array[(array * np.where(array)[0]) > threshold] = np.nan
```

You can extend this solution to two-dimensional arrays, however you need to determine how you want to define a two-dimensional index in your condition.

Here are the two indices (one for each dimension) you could plug into the conditional indexing:

```py
array = np.random.rand(5, 5)
indices = np.where(array)[0].reshape((5, 5))
print(indices)
>>> [[0 0 0 0 0]
     [1 1 1 1 1]
     [2 2 2 2 2]
     [3 3 3 3 3]
     [4 4 4 4 4]]
indices = np.where(array)[1].reshape((5, 5))
print(indices)
>>> [[0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]
     [0 1 2 3 4]]
```